# Add an XNode of varying content to an element

Tags: c#, xml

*NOTE*

Please note, read the comments if you want the missing link to this solution - it's not in the question that this is an "exact duplicate" of.

I'm stumped by the need for a little bit of XML gymnastics. Maybe I'm over complicating this.

I'm trying to add a `p` element to an XML document. The content of the paragraph may be plain text. Or may have elements within it, i.e link tags, styling, etc.

The code I have currently is below:

```
foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
{
    doc.Add(new XElement("p", 
        new XElement("a", new XAttribute("type", "paranum"), new XText(_paragraphCount)),
        new XText(paragraph.Content)));
}
```

When I use this, however, any elements that are in there don't come through as elements, but are escaped, probably because they're in XText.

However, I seem to recall trying `XElement.Parse`, but it not liking it when there is no root element, which makes sense. Sometimes, there aren't even any elements, just text.

How would I go about putting the content of this paragraph in the p element and preserving child elements, if any? Preferably without wrapping it in another element to allow me to do `XElement.Parse`.

Comment: Why don't you want to wrap it in another element?

Comment: Well, I'll try the accepted answer for that question, but are you sure it will handle scenarios where there are no inner tags at all, just XText?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer works - I checked it.

Comment: @dbc Just tried this. No dice. The elements collection returns an empty collection. I want both the text and any contained elements. I'd have thought the parsing would've put the text in XText elements or something.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. If I use Nodes() rather than Elements() as that answer implies, I get what I'm after. That answer didn't get me the whole way there. I'm not so sure this is a duplicate question as it has a different answer. But hey...

Comment: Since this is an old question, you could ask the question again, then answer it yourself.

Comment: Posting another "duplicate" to iron out this little bit of knowledge left out in the answer I'm supposed to have found by seeming magic seems counterproductive.